# wordpress app works very slow on wampserver 2.5 localhost

Tags: wordpress, performance, woocommerce, wampserver

I have made a lot of changes but always home page takes 5 secs to load and backend is also more slow

My PC is CORE 2 DUO 2GH CPU & 2G RAM Window 7 32 bits WampServer 2.5

I have disabled  Cgi_module

I have changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 in System32/etc/hosts

I have updated this define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'); in wp-config

I have increased memory limit in php.ini to 512

and I restart server but nothing changed

knowing that I work with woocommerce plugin
and I have two others apps without cms (native php, mysql), they works fast

UPDATE :

I have made those mysql tuning updates :

```
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port=3306
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
```

Comment: Have you tried tuning MySQL ? Increasing PHP memory wont speed up MYSQL

Comment: I have changed some vars in mysql, see update

Comment: Is this WP using MYISAM or INNODB

Comment: default one, I don't change anything, I just downloaded it three days ago, but in my others apps, I work with MyIsam to speed up mysql queries